# Slightly complicated object map

Tags: c#, winforms, ninject, inversion-of-control, mvp

I have a presenter to handle the behaviour of my form something like this:

```
public class Form1Presenter
{
    IForm1View _view;
    IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    IService1 _service1;
    IService2 _service;

    public Form1Presenter(
        IForm1View view,
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        IService1 service1,
        IService2 service2)
    {
        _view = view;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _service1 = service1;
        _service2 = service2;
    }
}
```

The services are injected with the same unit of work object as is injected into the presenter above. Like this:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public Service1(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

To create Form1Presenter by hand, I'd have to do something like this:

```
public class Form1 : Form, IForm1View
{
    public Form1()
    {
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        IService1 service1 = new Service1(unitOfWork);
        IService1 service2 = new Service2(unitOfWork);
        Form1Presenter presenter = new Form1Presenter(this, unitOfWork, service1, service2);
    }
}
```

Is there a nice way to do this with Ninject? I'm new to this and can't seem to work it out.

Comment: You will have to use a scope to make sure `service1`, `service2` and `Form1Presenter` get injected the same `IUnitOfWork` instance. Also, what's the life time (management) of your `IUnitOfWork`?

Comment: Yes, a scope sounds like the thing I need. A new instance of IUnitOfWork is created for each form.

Comment: [This is an interesting article](http://kohari.org/2009/03/06/cache-and-collect-lifecycle-management-in-ninject-20/). If I was coding a webpage I would use InRequestScope. An activation block seems to do the trick, but it pollutes my code with Ninject specifics that I was hoping to limit to the composition root.

Comment: don't (ever) use `ActivationBlock`, it will be removed from ninject and has some other side effects complicating things *a lot*.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the ActivationBlock. Like I said, I'm new to Ninject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to create a unit of work for each form. I'm not going into whether that is a sensible choice or not.

There's several ways to achieve this:

### **1 - manual management**

```
var unitOfWork = IResolutionRoot.Get<IUnitOfWork>();
IResolutionRoot.Get<Form1Presenter>(new ConstructorArgument("unitOfWork", unitOfWork, true);
```

Here you have ninject create a unit of work, then request a form and put the unitOfWork as ConstructorArgument on the request. The form and all it's dependencies which use the unitOfWork need to have a constructor parameter `IUnitOfWork unitOfWork`. The name needs to be same as specified in the constructor argument.

So this is quite a lot of work and does not make use of all the sweetnees an IoC can provide. So i would not recommend using this approach.

### **2 Named Scope**

Have a look at [Ninject Named Scope Extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope).
Create the bindings as follows:

```
const string UnitOfWorkScopeName = "UnitOfWorkScopeName";

IBindingRoot.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>()
            .InNamedScope(UnitOfWorkScopeName);

IBindingRoot.Bind<Form1Presenter>().ToSelf()
            .DefinesNamedScope(UnitOfWorkScopeName);
IBindingRoot.Bind<Form2Presenter>().ToSelf()
            .DefinesNamedScope(UnitOfWorkScopeName);
IBindingRoot.Bind<Form3Presenter>().ToSelf()
            .DefinesNamedScope(UnitOfWorkScopeName);
```

This will result in all the object bound with `DefinesNamedScope` and all it's dependencies getting the same instance of `IUnitOfWork`.
However, you can never instanciate an `IUnitOfWork` when you are not in the correct scope. Thus all your forms need to define a (the same) scope. Also, a form may not depend on another form, because then you would have scope overlap.

### **3 Call Scope**

`InCallScope()` means that all objects created by one IResolutionRoot.Get() will receive the same object.

```
IBindingRoot.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>()
            .InCallScope();
```

The bindings of all other components does not need to be adjusted.

This does not work in case you are instanciating multiple forms by one call to `IResolutionRoot.Get()`

---

Of course there's even more ways how you can manage the lifetime of a unit of work.
We have decoupled session management from IUnitOfWork and use a `ThreadLocal` to determine whether we need to start a new session/transaction or use an existing one.

Comment: The InCallScope() sounds promising, I'll give it a try later today and mark your answer as accepted if all goes to plan. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions) and then you can bind all classes to their default interface (class name with an "I" in front) like this

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind(x =>
                x.FromThisAssembly()         // Scans currently assembly
                 .IncludingNonePublicTypes() // Including Non-public types
                 .SelectAllClasses()         // Retrieve all non-abstract classes
                 .BindDefaultInterface());   // Binds the default interface to them, e.g. class name without preceding "I"
var Form1Presenter = kernel.Get<Form1Presenter>();
```